# Disable spell checking in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, spell-check

How can I disable spell checking in Firefox? This is *not* a trivial question. The normal option to turn it off does not work. Version is 29.1

Here is a screenshot showing the option turned off yet spell checking is still happening:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that is a Firefox issue? The same thing happens on Chrome and IE so it might be Google doing spell check on your searches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is done by Google, not the browser.

As you can see in the image below, if you inspect the code, you can see it uses the class `gsc_b`

If you remove this class (or overwrite it using GreaseMonkey or similar) the misspelt word is no longer underlined.

[image]

Comment: Thus, a user stylesheet which disables that CSS rule should do the trick, if Google never decides to allow users to turn it off... https://gist.github.com/sbai/10001777